# Top of font cut off in safari

Tags: html, css, fonts, safari

My site is working well in Chrome and firefox, but in safari, teh top of the font is cut away[image: As seen on Chrome]

[image: As seen on safari]

The font is Futura

Comment: try another font and see if the problem persists, if not it's more likely a font-rendering issue

Comment: Yes, it happens only in that particular font. But I quite like that font..

Comment: Did you try setting the line height, e.g. `line-height: 2;`

Comment: line-height doesn't help in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this  `text-rendering:optimizeLegibility;` and see if it helps if not try this too 
`-webkit-font-feature-settings: "kern" 1;`